# I can't uninstall vue from ubuntu

Tags: vue.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hello i'm working on WSL and to run my vue project i need vue 2.9.0
and `vue -V` shows vue 2.9.6
I'v tried comand `npm uninstall @vue/cli` and `npm uninstall -g @vue/cli`
but `vue -V` still shows vue 2.9.6
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clear the cache?

The following should work:

`npm uninstall -g @vue/cli`

`npm clear cache --force`

If you are using the older version of vue cli (1.x or 2.x) like you are, then you can uninstall it like this.

`npm uninstall -g vue-cli`

Comment: The proper comand is `npm cashe clean --force` then  for check ` npm cache verify ` but version is still 2.9.6

Comment: did you try `npm uninstall -g vue-cli`  or the `@vue/cli` ?

Comment: You are right problem was with corect comand to version. Finale answer is - when use vue 2  and you want to downgrade version use comand `npm install -g vue-cli@2.6.0`